# Store data local to a specific instance of a page in a jQuery Mobile multi-page application

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile multi-page application, that allows the user to navigate between pages using links or the browser back button.

I'd like to store some data or a flag in a specific page instance and read it again when the user navigates back to that page. The data should be local to the specific instance in the browser history stack and not available in other instances, like if the user navigates to the page again, going forward through links.

How would I store such data, or get a reference to instance of the page?

Ideally it would be something like `$.mobile.uniqueActivePageInstance.data("attribute", "value")`

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3efdjbex/

Comment: no @Omar your solution does store data in a page, but what I want is this: I navigate to a page, then to a different page and then to the first page again. I'd like to store different data in each of those two instances of the page I visited twice.

Comment: Ok, you want to store data in page1 before navigating to page2, then store data in page2 before navigating back to page1, when page1 is shown again you want to store different data? Pls correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I want to store data in page1, then navigate to page2, then navigate again to page1 (following a forward link) and store different data in page1. If I then hit the back button twice to go back to page1, I would like to read my old data from page1.

Comment: It's complicated, don't you think? You'll need to create a separate history navigation system to store all navigation action as well as data. Its doable but requires a good implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the history state of the current element of the history stack to store the data:

Write:

```
history.replaceState($.extend(history.state, {myData: myDataObjectOrString}));
```

Read:

```
history.state.myData;
```